# Is there is any way to learn the names of people who were working on the preparation of the Vilna Shas?

Tags: talmud-gemara, historical-figures, publications

A lot of people worked on [the Romm's Vilna Talmud published in 1880](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilna_Edition_Shas). Is there is any way to get their names?

Comment: Welcome!  That Wiki page has a couple of links, if you didn't read the one about the Romm Publishing house, please go ahead and do it--it names some of the folks involved in proofreading, designing the font, and printing it.  There were probably lots of others involved...someone here might know where to find the scholarship on the production of it.

Comment: You might have better luck over on [History.SE]. Mi Yodeya isn’t particularly conducive to questions about Jewish history, except as it pertains to the religion, not just its practitioners. This seems to fail that criterion, since it’s asking about those (maybe not even Jewish, for all we know) who put together a particular edition of the Talmud; if this were about those who originally compiled the Talmud, this would be fine, but as it stands, this seems to be off-topic. That doesn’t mean it’s a bad question - just that this isn’t the place to ask it.

Comment: When I asked the question, I was fully aware that this may not be the place which has people familiar with the actual Jewish history. Thanks anyway.